# Is Altestadt a variation of Altstadt?

Tags: translation, difference, usage

I just wonder if being an adjective the word Alt in the word Altstadt would be correct in the inflected form as Altestadt? Clarifying, I was asking why the prefix (alt) doesn’t follow the inflected form referring to the noun (Stadt). And finally if it’s a contraction that just happened or there is a rule for this, that is present in other words.

Comment: It’s hard to tell what you really want to know. Yes, "alte Stadt" is grammatically correct, but it does not mean the same as "Altstadt", although they certainly are related.

Comment: Hello user40208, good questions in this forum demonstrate some effort of the person asking to solve the problem by her/his own means, e.g. by looking up things in dictionaries or other resources and laying out the problem with some consideration.

Comment: Do you expect "Altstadt" to be a special case in any way, or are you asking whether noun prefixes that apparently match the root of an adjective can also use an inflected form of the adjective?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann sorry for insulting your intelligence...if a question is not clear, the person replying, if wants to reply can make some effort asking for clarification. Simply.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes, sorry for the typo, actually I was asking why the prefix (alt) doesn’t follow the inflected form referring to the noun (stadt)...in general if it’s something common in other words, also.

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer:** No, you cannot say *Altestadt* instead of *Altstadt*.

**Long answer:** You encountered a composition of an adjective and a noun.

First, even though such compositions may have been derived from phrases in that both the adjective and the noun stood alone, compositions have developed their own specific meanings. For example, *die Altstadt* refers to the historic district of a city, whereas *eine alte Stadt* is simply an old town.

Second, such compositions are formed using only the stem of the adjective; in other words, the inflection ending of the adjective is omitted. Here are some examples:

- groß + Mutter → Großmutter (≠ große Mutter)
- weit + Sprung → Weitsprung (≠ weiter Sprung)
- blau + Helm → Blauhelm (≠ blauer Helm)
- hoch + Haus → Hochhaus (≠ hohes Haus)
- neu + Stadt → Neustadt (≠ neue Stadt)
- alt + Stadt → Altstadt (≠ alte Stadt)
- ...